# Setting onclick dynamically and passing in the element itself

Tags: vbscript, onclick, dhtml

`element.onclick= aFunction()` does not call the function when `element` (in this case a `<SPAN>` element) is clicked.

This question has been answered for JavaScript (question by Nick Van Hoogenstyn), but how do you do the same sort of thing for VBScript? The reason why I'm using VBScript instead of JavaScript is that I'm creating an HTA and using VBScript for the file access activities within it.

Answer (score 1):

This

[image: span on click II]

demonstrates that this simple code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <Title>spanclick</Title>
  <hta:application id="spanclick" scroll = "no">
  <script type="text/vbscript">
   Function onSpanClick(oElm)
     MsgBox oElm.tagName & " onSpanClick clicked"
   End Function
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span onclick="onSpanClick Me">onSpanClick</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

'works' by putting the function name into the onclick attribute of the span element and passing the element (Me) to the function.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript is little bit different form Javascript in Syntax

see the sample

```
<script language="vbscript">
 sub cmdBtn_Click()
 msgbox("Click!!!")
 end sub
 </script>

    <input type="button" name="cmdBtn" value="Click Me!" onclick ="vbscript:cmdBtn_Click">
```